# Crystal Reports Viewer does not display in browser on one server, yet does on an almost identical server

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have two Amazon EC2 instances that are just about exactly identical. (set up the first one, made an image of it and then created a new instance from this). The only difference on the 2nd server is that the application directory is on a side drive (E), not the main drive (C). If i navigate to the site hosted on the first server (which has the application directory on C) the report displays. On the other server where the directory is on the E drive the page loads but there is no report displayed - It just appears as a blank page.

I installed and reinstalled the CRforVS runtime (using the older 13.0.2 on both) yet this doesn't seem to let us view the report on the 2nd server. Is this because when the MSI runs it installs to C and the site contained on E is not looking in the correct place for the resources? Listed below is the section of my web.config that handles the CR runtime.

```
        <compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="vb" targetFramework="4.0">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
        </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Thank you.

edit - i found a little information that deals with if there is no "C" drive - http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/d02f7cd3-f18b-2d10-55ad-dab2200f68fc?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&53240414858625

wasn't sure if this applied in my situation since there is a c drive, just the site is not located on this drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read in many posts that the msi installer will sometimes not install correctly and the folks at SAP alwas recommend using the exe instead of the msi.
I have been looking around but couldn't find version 13.0.2, the only link I could find is 13.0.5, which is [here](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_3.exe). This will automatically download the exe. You might want to check the SAP forums some more for that issue, it is quite common and I had the same issue back in the day.

Hope that helps,

Chris

EDIT: Found it. [Here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) is the download site which points out to use the exe and not the msi and it has the 13.0.2 version, too. So I think what you want is the click-once zip file which contains the exe. You may want to uninstall the current version before reinstalling with the exe.

Comment: thank you so much. i will attempt this and post back with the results.

Comment: when downloading the click once zip for 13.0.2 there is no .exe file to install. I tried to install using the install executable link for 13.0.2 but it fails because I do not have visual studio installed on the production server.

Comment: I'm confused, I thought the servers were identical? You will need a Crystal runtime on each server in order to view reports. So what is on the server where you CAN view the reports?

Comment: was able to solve from this, since there was no exe - i moved the site back to c and reinstalled the MSI and it is working correctly. Seems like you need to use a newer version to do this as stated above. Stuck for now on 13.0.2 for consistency reasons